# Terminal user/machine information changed?

Tags: 10.04, gnome-terminal

I'm using 10.04 lucid. I did some change i don't remember in /etc/hosts or hostname file that now when i open terminal it shows

`none@root`

I want to change the none to whatever like machine-name? How can i change it back.

Answer (score 1):

Open `/etc/hostname` file and change the name

```
gksudo gedit /etc/hostname
```

You can use `hostname` command check the current hostname used by your system.